# How to get started with SoftHSM

Tags: windows, security, softhsm

I am currently trying to get a SoftHSM going (on a Windows platform). The goal is establish a communication channel between a client and the HSM server so that some data can be encrypted on the server side and be sent back to the calling client.

I download one from this site: https://www.opendnssec.org/download/

Furthermore, I followed the documentation as stated on this page: https://wiki.opendnssec.org/display/SoftHSMDOCS/SoftHSM+Documentation+Home - but besides from creating a couple of slots, I haven't managed to get anything right.

I ran the following command to create the slot(s):

```
softhsm --init-token --slot 0 --label "My token 1"
```

I am not sure how to go from here, I cannot find any useful information / tutorials about the topic. I guess that I should start small and try and create a server application that communicates to the SoftHSM ... I apologize for all the n00b questions!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the installation was successful
in `/usr/local/bin/softshm` there should be the file `libsofthsm.so`.

This file contains the implementation of `crytoki api` - 
and you can use it like- so/dll that comes with hardware of `pkcs#11`

Comment: currently when you install from https://github.com/opendnssec/SoftHSMv2, you get the SO in /usr/local/lib/softhsm/libsofthsm2.so